# JavaScript Background Sync Stops Working if Page is Loaded/Refreshed while offline

Tags: javascript, service-worker, background-sync

I'm currently learning how to use Background Sync as to allow users to PUT/POST changes while using a web app offline.

I followed the instructions given by Jake Archibald in 
[Introducing Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) , and everything worked great... as long as I register the Background Sync when the web app was loaded while being **online**. What I mean by that is:

### Steps that work:

1. While online I open web app
2. I turn **offline mode** on in the network tab
3. I click some buttons that register a Background Sync.
4. I turn **offline mode** off, so app goes back online.
5. Background Sync is triggered.

### Steps that cause it to stop working:

It stops working completely, even in the above scenario if I do the following:

1. While on a different site, I turn **offline mode** on in the network tab.
2. I navigate to my web app, which is available offline thanks to the service worker.
3. I click some buttons that are supposed to register a Background Sync.
4. I turn **offline mode** off in the network tab.
5. Nothing happens.
6. After I go to the Application tab, and unregister the service worker, and try again from a fresh installation, the first steps work, but the second set of steps keeps breaking the Background Sync

### Code:

In page:

```js
//requesting a one-off sync:
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (reg) {
  return reg.sync.register('sync-tag');
}).catch(function (e) {
  console.error(e, "System was unable to register for a sync");
});
```

In Service Worker

```js
self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
  if (event.tag == 'sync-tag') {
    event.waitUntil( doStuff() )
  }
});
```

## Update

When the code works, I used the following code to keep track of tags sent to registration:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (reg) {
  console.log('before', reg.sync.getTags());
  reg.sync.register('sync-tag');
  console.log('after', reg.sync.getTags());
}).catch(function (e) {
  console.error(e, "System was unable to register for a sync");
});
```

When using the steps that work, I get

```
before: resolved to an empty array
after: resolved to an array with one tag ['sync-tag']
```

When using the steps that cause it to stop working:

```
before: resolved to an array with one tag ['sync-tag']
after: resolved to the same array above
```

This leads me to believe the sync registration happens, but the service worker isn't `listening` anymore. And no matter what I do, like close the browser tab, refresh the page when online, wait a while, the service worker just won't `listen` to sync events anymore.

I understand that is up to the browser to decide when to make the Background Sync, but I just don't understand why this isn't working. Unless the expected behavior is to expect the user to visit the web app when online, I think I'm getting something wrong.

Thank you for your patience, and any help understanding how to make Background Sync work will be appreciated.

Comment: I have same thing happend in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942049/javascript-background-sync-android-power-button)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I feel stupid. The browser is indeed the one that decides when to do the background sync.

The behavior I expected is wrong:

1. Access app while offline.
2. POST/PUT changes with Background Sync
3. Go back online, refresh page see changes right away

Behavior the browser actually implemented:

### Accessing app while online:

1. Access app online.
2. app goes offline (manually or not)
3. POST/PUT changes with Background Sync
4. app goes online, and refresh
5. Changes are instant, since Sync happens as soon as app goes online. Browser is able to detect the change from online, to offline back to online?

### Accessing app while offline

1. Access app while offline.
2. POST/PUT changes with Background Sync.
3. app goes online, and refresh
4. Changes aren't instant. Somehow the browser decides not to make the sync yet.
5. Close browser completely, and come back to page
6. The Browser syncs.

So is hard to know when the Browser will perform the sync, and only when accessing app while online, does the browser syncs if it detects a change from offline then online in same session (no refresh?)